# until vs before

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What's the difference between until and before in this sentence?

> He won't be home until/before noon.

I know the general difference between the two words, but in this particular sentence they seem to have the same meaning.

Are they both correct? Do they convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct but they say slightly different things.

> He won't be home  before noon.

says that you don't know when he will be home but you know it won't be in the morning.

> He won't be home until  noon.

suggests that you will in fact find him at home in the afternoon.